# (8 out of range 6) Underscore.js Templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, requirejs-text

I am using Backbone.js and underscore.js with Requirejs. However when i try to load my view template, it gives me (8 out of range 6) error in Underscore.js line 8. 
Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
var imageView = new ImageView({model: item});


define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','imageview','text!../templates/template_image.html'], 
function($, _, Backbone, ImageView, template){
        var ImageView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                this.showImageTemplate = _.template(template);              
            },
            render: function(){
                var html = this.showImageTemplate(this.model);
                this.$el.html(html);
                return this;
            }
        });
    return ImageView;
});
```

And my Template file:

```
<img id="frameImg" src="<%= DocumentPath %>/<%= DocumentName %>" alt="image" title="image"/>
```

Comment: Also, when i try to console.log(this.model) in render function, it shows me my complete model but i get error when i run my code:

ReferenceError: DocumentPath is not defined(8 out of range 6)

PS. DocumentPath is included in Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the raw `Backbone.Model` object as data to your template, so you're working with something like

```
{       
    _changing: false,
    _pending: false,
    _previousAttributes: {}
    attributes: {
        DocumentPath: "", 
        DocumentName: ""
    }
    ...
}
```

You probably only want the attributes, which you can obtain via [`model.toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) for example. Try :

```
var html = this.showImageTemplate(this.model.toJSON());
```

Comment: Thanks, it was this problem. I didnt realized my mistake before.
Its working now, thanks again :)